# Targeting build for Worklight 6.2

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing on Eclipse Juno SR2 with MobileFirst 7.x installed from Eclipse Market Place.

However, my target server is Worklight 6.2. How do I create a .wlapp build for targeting to 6.2 version? There doesn't seem to be a target version to choose from in eclipse.

The build I create has a platformversion 7.x which is failing to install in Worklight 6.2 console.

Answer (score 0):

There is no backwards compatibility for what you are attempting.

You cannot run MobileFirst 7.1 apps on Worklight 6.2; these are very very different releases that are simply not compatible.

If you develop using 7.1, use 7.1.

Comment: Whats the best way to get 6.2 dev tools in eclipse? I could not find much resources online. It's 7.1 everywhere. Also I understand the 7.1 build won't work on 6.1, but 7.1 tools should allow to build for previos releases, we shouldn't have to maintain to IDEs for two servers. Thanks

Comment: Are you an IBM Customer? You can find 6.2 iFixes in the IBM Fix Central website. You can also find links in the Worklight/MobileFirst developer center... https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/

Comment: So upgrading the server is not an option at the moment for us. We have to release an app into 6.2 production server(assuming it cannot be upgraded to 7.1).  I have access to those fixes which we will eventually apply. I may just end up opening a PMR to find IDE that can target 6.2. Thanks

Comment: Alternatively, if you can share a sample iOS native .wlapp archive, i can manually edit the 7.1 to 6.2. Here's a differetn question i posted - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488975/worklight-6-2-wlapp-deployment-data-file-format

Comment: I don't see the point in the PMR. If you use 6.2 server, use 6.2 studio(!)