# Worklight 6.2 .wlapp deployment.data file format

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I need to deploy an application to Worklight 6.2, but the latest IDE i have only targets for MobileFirst 7.1. I am trying to manually edit the meta/dployment.data file(pasted below). I updated the platform.version to 6.2 manually. Can someone help me with:

1. If someone can share a sample .wlapp archive targetted for WL 6.2, specifically iOSNative app with authentication disabled.
2. Or if someone can help me plug the right values into below file. Mainly this value "app.authenticity.obscuredata=23.507-9.852-31.807"

This is the content of XYZ.wlapp/meta/deployment.data file

```
#Deployment data.
#Tue Mar 01 14:06:35 PST 2016
app.build.time=1456869995617
app.displayname=RLReplen
platform.version=6.2.0.01.20141027-1531
app.target.category=UNDEFINED
app.ios.bundle.id=com.pr.RLReplen
app.version=1.0
app.environment=iOSnative
app.license.type=APPLICATION
app.description=A native iOS applicatio
app.native=true
app.authenticity.obscuredata=23.507-9.852-31.807
app.id=RLReplen
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible, as explained in your previous question.

If you need the Studio for 6.2, then do not install Studio from Eclipse marketplace, as from there you get only the latest studio - 7.1. The latest is simply not backwards compatible, nor can it be as the product has changed significantly. You also cannot take a 7.1 project and open it in Studio 6.2 and expect it to work... or start altering it.

You need to create a new 6.2 project using Studio 6.2, and copy your implementation into it.

Please go to IBM Fix Central, download Studio for your build level (6.2), and install it manually into your Eclipse. And use that.

Only 6.2 studio will produce 6.2 server compatible projects, applications, adapters and any other artifacts.